# Database structure for a bilingual dictionary

Tags: database-design

I've search all over and can't find advice of a good database structure for a bilingual dictionary, how would you define the structure for an English-Spanish language bilingual dictionary?

Answer (score 4):

In a document store:

```
{
    {
        "language": "English",
        "word": "cat"
    },
    {
        "language": "Spanish",
        "word": "gato"
    }
}
```

Of course you'll have to choose a working language for the keys.

In a graph DB, add each word from each language as a node. Label the nodes with the language. Alternatively have a separate node for the language itself and connect the word-node to the language-node. Then connect word-nodes in one language to the corresponding word-node in another language. Note that English has a lot of words imported from other languages so decide whether you have one word-node connected to several languages or separate word-nodes.

In a relational database I would have a table for the languages, one for word lists and a third for equivalences

```
table: Languages
    Language_name   primary key

table: Words
    language_name
    word
```

Both columns together make a composite primary key

```
table: Transaltions
    first_language_name
    first_word
    second_language_name
    second_word
```

The primary key is all four columns. During lookup should you compare the given word to first_word or second_word? Either maintain a conventions and stick with it (Spanish = first_, English = second_) or query both and deal with the few (but non-zero) collisions).

Some concepts do not translate word-for-word. This could be handled by renaming column "word" to "idea" or "phrase".

For multi-lingual (rather than just bilingual) lists having an over-arching concept which has word-forms in each language would be one way to go:

```
Table: Concepts
    concept_id

Table: Translations
    concept_id
    language_name
    word
```

To go from "cat" (English), find the corresponding row in Translations. From that find the concept_id. Then read the concept_id, language_name row in Spanish. Homonyms make this difficult, however.